# Disable webview browser tester ( android )

Tags: android

I download last version of android studio , keep all up to date.
 VERSION is 2.2.2 .

I cant find how to remove tester browser from my app . I just wanna to use webView control not browser tester .

Comment: I am looking for the same solution. It didn't happen in previous versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed it. I forgot to add this line:

`WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

What heppend was that it actually opened the browser after redirecting instead of the WebView.
For some reason it opens this webview tester instead of the browser, so it's misleading.

Full code:

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://...");
```

Comment: I have same problem that when open a url from sms, webview tester app jump up and open this url. I have another application which have a webview client and i want to use this app to navigate all URL. I am doing same way as above code mentioned but seems to be not working for me. Any idea ?

Comment: Is there a solution for < API 26?